# How to manage text on Mapael map when hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, mapael

I have a real mystery to solve.

So I have a Mapel map rendered and 3 tspans inside text on this area:

[image]

[third text is smaller and kindof above second text next to it and looks lovely]

Aaaaaand when I hover on area:

[image]

[third text falls back to its origin* position]

When mouse is no longer over specific area, it still is not where it supposed to be:

[image]

[third text falls back to its origin* position]

[*origin means that I update position of given text using *afterInit* and *afterUpdate* event and without my ingerention it would look like that, which I DON'T want to]

Can anyone help, how can I make the third text to stop returning to original position?

**Disclaimer**: these objects are svg text elements and **no** css changing their position would work. Their position is defined by **dy** and **dx**, BUT when hover, **dy** is changing and updating itself. I need to really smart AND simple to work this around.